# Failed migration attempt. Errors with TF26176: Could not connect to the specified Azure DevOps Server collection URL

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am attempting to initiate my 1st migration between a local TFS server and Azure DevOps. I've checked my config.json source and target urls and don't see any issues with the url and project name but when I execute the migration tool I receive the following errors. It seems to connect to both TFS and Azure servers but cannot configure the store. Could this be a permissions related issue?

```
MigrationClient: Access granted to https://mycompanysiteurl/TFS/ for PaulB (Domain\Paul.B)
[16:14:34 ERR] Unable to configure store
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ConnectionException: TF26176: Could not connect to the specified Azure DevOps Server collection URL. Please check the URL and try again.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.GetWorkItemStore(WorkItemStoreFlags bypassRules) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 263
[16:14:34 INF] TfsMigrationClient::GetDependantTfsCollection:AuthenticationMode(Prompt)
[16:14:34 INF] TfsMigrationClient::GetDependantTfsCollection: Prompting for credentials
[16:14:34 INF] MigrationClient: Connecting to https://mycompanysite.visualstudio.com/
[16:14:34 INF] MigrationClient: validating security for {"IsContainer": false, "UniqueName": "Paul.B@mycompany.com", "Descriptor": {"Data": null, "Identifier": "01de0b06-87b5-4eae-b09a-fe502ac4fb83\\Paul.B@mycompany.com", "IdentityType": "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity", "$type": "IdentityDescriptor"}, "DisplayName": "Paul B", "IsActive": true, "MemberOf": [], "Members": [], "TeamFoundationId": "865d9407-523f-60ed-af45-f3bf28a87f9b", "UniqueUserId": 0, "$type": "TeamFoundationIdentity"}
[16:14:34 INF] MigrationClient: Access granted to https://companysite.visualstudio.com/ for Paul B (Paul.B@mycompany.com)
[16:14:34 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ConnectionException: TF26176: Could not connect to the specified Azure DevOps Server collection URL. Please check the URL and try again.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.GetWorkItemStore(WorkItemStoreFlags bypassRules) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 279
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.InnerConfigure(IMigrationClient migrationClient, Boolean bypassRules) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 202
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsMigrationClient.Configure(IMigrationClientConfig config, NetworkCredential credentials) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsMigrationClient.cs:line 83
   at MigrationTools.MigrationEngine.GetSource() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\MigrationEngine.cs:line 146
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 83
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
```